# Adding a div Read More wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Ok so I am trying to add a div read more button but it's not working, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

here is the code I am trying to use.

```
<?php the_content('<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php printf( __('Permalink to %s', 'wpbx'), the_title_attribute('echo=0') ) ?>" rel="bookmark"><div class="readmore"></div></a>') ?>
```

here is the css

```
.readmore{
  width:136px;
  height:34px;
  background: url('http://ericavain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/READ1.png') no-repeat;
}
.readmore:hover{
  width:136px;
  height:34px;
  background: url('http://ericavain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/read2.png') no-repeat;
}
```

How do i get this accomplished

Comment: have you tried adding the class to the <a> link instead of a <div>? and change it to do it based on a.readmore{}

Comment: yes i have tried `<a class="readmore"></a>` that didn't work

Comment: what is your current page output?

Comment: What do you mean by page output

Comment: Well there must be something else going on as your current script is setup to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/xez22/  I was referring to PHP/HTML output or even site link.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to use "read more" on Pages? If that is the case try adding something like this to your page:

```
<?php  // let's enable more link on pages...
        global $more;
        $more = 0;
        ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
```